# error: ‘shared_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’ using ReaderLock = std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>;

Tags: c++, cmake, cryptography

i'm trying to use microsoft SEAL library for homomorphic encryption and following the steps from the below link https://github.com/cyberweapons/SEAL/blob/master/INSTALL.txt
when i use command       cmake .
terminal shows below result

```
-- SEAL detected (version 2.3.1)
-- SEAL build type: Release
-- SEAL debug mode: OFF
-- SEAL using Microsoft GSL: OFF
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ravindra/Desktop/../../MiSEAL/SEAL/SEALExamples
```

after that when i give make command it should generate a file main.cpp.o instead it is giving the following errors.

```
 [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/main.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/seal/util/mempool.h:12:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/memorypoolhandle.h:6,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/biguint.h:6,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/bigpoly.h:9,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/seal.h:3,
                 from /home/ravindra/Desktop/SakhaProjects/S20_AI/MiSEAL/SEAL/SEALExamples/main.cpp:12:
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:12:45: error: ‘shared_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
         using ReaderLock = std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>;
                                             ^~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:12:45: error: ‘shared_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:12:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         using ReaderLock = std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>;
                                                              ^
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:14:45: error: ‘shared_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
         using WriterLock = std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>;
                                             ^~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:14:45: error: ‘shared_mutex’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:14:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         using WriterLock = std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>;
                                                              ^
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:21:20: error: ‘ReaderLock’ does not name a type
             inline ReaderLock acquire_read()
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:26:20: error: ‘WriterLock’ does not name a type
             inline WriterLock acquire_write()
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:31:20: error: ‘ReaderLock’ does not name a type
             inline ReaderLock try_acquire_read()
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:36:20: error: ‘WriterLock’ does not name a type
             inline WriterLock try_acquire_write()
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/seal/util/locks.h:46:18: error: ‘shared_mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
             std::shared_mutex rw_lock_mutex_;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/seal/memorypoolhandle.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/biguint.h:6,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/bigpoly.h:9,
                 from /usr/local/include/seal/seal.h:3,
                 from /home/ravindra/Desktop/SakhaProjects/S20_AI/MiSEAL/SEAL/SEALExamples/main.cpp:12:
/usr/local/include/seal/util/mempool.h: In member function ‘virtual int64_t seal::util::MemoryPoolMT::pool_count() const’:
/usr/local/include/seal/util/mempool.h:561:17: error: ‘ReaderLock’ was not declared in this scope
                 ReaderLock lock(pools_locker_.acquire_read());
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sealexamples.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i am new to SEAL library also i am a beginner to c++ programming, please someone help me to fix this issues.

Comment: It is called `std::shared_mutex`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::share_mutex`; I assume that's a typo. `std::shared_mutex` was added in C++17, and your compiler needs to support that (Which means a recent version of gcc or clang, and probably a command line option to enable C++17 mode).

Comment: i'm using gcc and as mentioned in documentation it needs support of gcc 6 + version, i tried using gcc from version 5.4 to latest, still i am unable to fix this issue.

Comment: @RaviSB0101 does the code have `#include <shared_mutex>`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found the solution,
i have included following commands in CMakeLists.txt file continued  with the steps
`

```
# Below is TFHE START
export TFHE_PREFIX=/usr/local
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${TFHE_PREFIX}/include:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=${TFHE_PREFIX}/include:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}
export LIBRARY_PATH=${TFHE_PREFIX}/lib:${LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${TFHE_PREFIX}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
# Below is TFHE END
```

`